# how to get offset in seconds for sydney (auto switch daylight saving)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone, timezone-offset, moment-timezone

Convert the timezone offset in seconds. How to do it in javascript?
I need the timezone offset in seconds for Australia/Sydney or as a string ('+10:00' or '+11:00') in Nodejs or Javascript?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Answer (score 1):

The getTimezoneOffset() method returns the time zone difference, in minutes.

```js
var myDate =  new Date();
var aestTime = myDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Australia/Sydney"});
var secondsOffset = ((new Date(aestTime).getTime() - myDate.getTime()) + 1000) / 1000;


function secondsToHours(n) {              
    var seconds = parseInt(n, 10); 
    var hours   = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((seconds - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    seconds = seconds - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);
    if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0" + hours;}
    if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0" + minutes;}
    var time = '+' + hours + ':' + minutes;
    return time;
}

console.log(secondsToHours(secondsOffset));
```

Comment: Also you can convert seconds to +hh:mm with this function. I hope this helps!

Comment: My server is running in UTC time. The above code is not giving Sydney offset +10:00 (or +11:00 based on daylight time)